# How to print array data in columns

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have code here that takes in two different array types, one boolean and one of ints.  I want to get the code to print like this

```
marked    edgeTo 
------   --------
true     2
true     0 
true     0 
true     5
true     3
true     0
```

I am currently using a foreach loop to print out the data and I cannot get edgeTo's data (2 0 0 5 3 0) to print underneath its title edgeTo and across from its respective marked boolean value. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Here is the snipet of code I have so far

```
System.out.println("marked    edgeTo");
System.out.println("-------   --------");

for (boolean el : bob.marked) {
    System.out.println(el);
}

for (int el : bob.edgeTo) {
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Comment: What is `marked` and `edgeTo`? --- Anyway, instead of parallel arrays/lists, you should have a single array/list of objects with 2 fields.

Comment: they're public fields of another class within my package I am working on. I am learning about depthfisrt search and marked is checks if there is a path from s-v. and edgeTo is the last on edge on the s-v path.

Answer (score 1):

if two arrays have same length, you can use 1 loop

```
 System.out.println("marked\tedgeTo");
 System.out.println("-------\t------");
 for (int i = 0; i < bob.marked.length;i++) {
   System.out.println(String.valueOf(bob.marked[i]) + "\t" +  String.valueOf(bob.edgeTo[i]));
 }
```

Comment: @Scary I edited.

Comment: Actually I was meaning the datatypes of `bob.marked` etc - maybe not an array.  I know notice that he does actually say array - my bad.

Comment: @htpvl thank you so much this worked.  I tried a for loop right after I posted my question, and I was very close I had the syntax wrong.  Thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: @Scary Wombat sorry my apologies yes they are arrays

Answer (score 1):

In case your arrays are of different lengths:

```
System.out.println("marked    edgeTo");
System.out.println("-------   --------");
int lesserArr = Math.min(bob.marked.length, bob.edgeTo.length);
for (int i = 0; i < lesserArr;i++) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(bob.marked[i]) + "\t" +  String.valueOf(bob.edgeTo[i]));
 }
for (int j = 0;j < Math.abs(bob.marked.length-bob.edgeTo.length); j++) {
    if (bob.marked.length < bob.edgeTo.length) 
        System.out.println("\t\t" +  String.valueOf(bob.edgeTo[lesserArr + j]));
    else
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(bob.marked[lesserArr + j]));
  }
}
```